# how to REMOVE a stretch in PyQt5 GUI?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

i'm trying to create a GUI application with PyQt5 which will add and remove pictures from the main window on button click (the window should have two buttons -  and ). 
I want the first picture to be at the beginning of the QHBoxLayout, the second one to be as close as posible to the first and so on. 
If i add stretch every time i create a new label - the window gets messed up when i try to delete pictures. So i wanted to REMOVE a stretch when i neet to remove a label and add one when i need to create one.
Ive searched the documentation but couldn't find anything but how to add a stretch, which i know.

So guys - if anyone could help me figure it out, or prupose another way i could do it - it'll help me a bunch.
thanks.

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: [QLayout.removeItem](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#removeItem).

Comment: i cant add pictuures  because im not privilaged - but cant you picture the app ? it adds images from the left to the right. like in any app - i want the images to sit tight to the left - how can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I have found the answer to your question! Although I am unaware of any way to remove stretch itself (I myself had the same question), I believe that you can use a QspacerItem to serve the same purpose as the added stretch. What's nice, is that the QspacerItem can be removed.

Here is what using a QspacerItem would look like

```
    self.stretchy_spacer_thing =QSpacerItem(10,10,QSizePolicy.Minimum,QSizePolicy.Expanding)
    self.some_Vbox_layout.addItem(self.stretchie)
```

you can then take away the spacer item when you don't need it with .removeItem()

```
     self.some_Vbox_layour.removeItem(self.stretchy_spacer_thing)
```

I'm new to using these things myself, so I don't know everything there is to know about them. But I just tried using it in some of my own code, and it seemed to work for me.